# ANDROID - ROOM - Pre populate database with a migration

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, database-migration

I know that using [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), I can create migrations between versions, like in this example where I updated the version of my database from 1 to 2 and implemented my RoomDatabase like this:

```kotlin
@Database(entities = [FooEntity::class, BarEntity::class], version = 2)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun fooDao(): FooDao
    abstract fun barDao(): BarDao
    
    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME: String = "my_database"

        val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("INSERT INTO foo (id, description) VALUES (1, \"Some text\"")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```kotlin
Room.databaseBuilder(androidContext(), MyDatabase::class.java, MyDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
    .build()
```

However, is it possible to create a "migration" to execute on the first time the app is installed?

I tried to created something like this, but it didn't work:

```kotlin
@Database(entities = [FooEntity::class, BarEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
 
    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME: String = "my_database"

        val MIGRATION_0_1 = object : Migration(0, 1) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("INSERT INTO foo (id, description) VALUES (1, \"Some text\"")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```kotlin
Room.databaseBuilder(androidContext(), MyDatabase::class.java, MyDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_0_1)
    .build()
```

I tried [Prepopulate from an app asset](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate#from-asset) some time ago, but I'm prety sure I got some problems with it reseting my database, so I'm not sure if it's the best option:

```kotlin
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, MyDatabase::class.java, "Sample.db")
    .createFromAsset("database/myapp.db")
    .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to execute code on database creation in Room is to set a callback on the database and override its `onCreate`:

```kotlin
Room.databaseBuilder(androidContext(), MyDatabase::class.java, MyDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
    .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO foo (id, description) VALUES (1, \"Some text\"")
        }
    })
    .build()
```

However, you should really consider the prepopulation [from assets](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate#from-asset) that you mention, particularly if the data to insert is large.